# DatagridView Row move Up Down

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUzMz.gif)

I move the row up or down in the datagridview.
I get an error like in the picture.
can you help me

Brn Up

```
 if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index != 0)
 {
     for (int j = 1; j < this.dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
     {
         object tmp = this.dataGridView1[j, dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Value;
         this.dataGridView1[j, dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Value = this.dataGridView1[j, dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index - 1].Value;
         this.dataGridView1[j, dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index - 1].Value = tmp;
     }
     int a = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
     dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
     this.dataGridView1.Rows[a - 1].Selected = true;
 }
```

Btn Down

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index != dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < this.dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        object tmp = this.dataGridView1[j, dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Value;
        this.dataGridView1[j, dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Value = this.dataGridView1[j, dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index + 1].Value;
        this.dataGridView1[j, dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index + 1].Value = tmp;
    }
    int i = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    this.dataGridView1.Rows[i + 1].Selected = true;
}
```

Btn Save

```
 DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
 try
 {
    
     using (SqlCommandBuilder scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda))
     {
         sda.Update(dt);
     }
     MessageBox.Show("Değişiklikler Kaydedildi.");
 }
 catch (Exception ee)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
 }
 listele();
```

thank you. good work.

Comment: what... were those button called and what error message did you get? pardon me, but i dont speak turkish.. also, the pop up message at the end of the gid is similar to your message in `MessageBox.Show("Değişiklikler Kaydedildi.");` no?

Comment: When we want to move it up, it copies the bottom row. and deletes the next row. Likewise, when I move down, it copies the bottom line and deletes the bottom line. click image above enter image description here

Answer (score 1):

You solved the problem myself again

MOVE UP

```
{
    for (int j = 1; j < this.dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        object tmp = this.dataGridView1[j, dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Value;
        this.dataGridView1[j, dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Value = this.dataGridView1[j, dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index - 1].Value;
        this.dataGridView1[j, dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index - 1].Value = tmp;
    }
    DataGridView dgv = dataGridView1;
    int totalRows = dgv.Rows.Count;
    int rowIndex = dgv.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Index;
    if (rowIndex == 0)
    return;
    int colIndex = dgv.SelectedCells[0].OwningColumn.Index;
    DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dgv.Rows[rowIndex];
    dgv.ClearSelection();
    dgv.Rows[rowIndex - 1].Cells[colIndex].Selected = true;
}

Move down

   if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index != dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2)
    {
    for (int j = 1; j < this.dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        object tmp = this.dataGridView1[j, 
    dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Value;
        this.dataGridView1[j, dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index].Value = 
  this.dataGridView1[j, dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index + 1].Value;
        this.dataGridView1[j, dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index + 1].Value = tmp;
    }
    DataGridView dgv = dataGridView1;
    int totalRows = dgv.Rows.Count;
    int rowIndex = dgv.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Index;
    if (rowIndex == totalRows - 1)
        return;
    int colIndex = dgv.SelectedCells[0].OwningColumn.Index;
    DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dgv.Rows[rowIndex];
    dgv.ClearSelection();
    dgv.Rows[rowIndex + 1].Cells[colIndex].Selected = true;
}
```